# How to keep line breaks while saving to SQL database and retrieving it to show inside a label

Tags: c#, css, asp.net

I have a textarea where I enter some text in multiple lines by pressing enter:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tbMessage" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" 
     TextMode="MultiLine" Columns="30" Rows="5"></asp:TextBox>
```

I save the text from code-behind (`MessageText` column is of type `varchar`):

```
using (SqlCommand qSave = new SqlCommand())
{
    qSave.Connection = oCon;
    qSave.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    qSave.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO [Db1].[dbo].[Table1] (MessageText) VALUES (@MessageText)";
    qSave.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MessageText", tbMessage.Text);

    try
    {
        oCon.Open();
        qSave.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (SqlException ce)
    {
    }
    finally
    {
        oCon.Close();
    }
}
```

I retrieve the column and show it inside a label from code-behind:

```
public void MyFunction()
{
    strSql = @"SELECT * FROM [Db1].[dbo].[Table1]";

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(gloString))
    {
        try
        {
            // create data adapter
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(strSql, conn);
            // this will query your database and return the result to your datatable

            myDataSet = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(myDataSet);

            string specific = "";
            string generic = "";
            string strTemp = "";

            foreach (DataRow r in myDataSet.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                if (r["MessageText"].ToString().Length <= 65)
                {
                    strTemp = r["MessageText"].ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    strTemp = TruncateLongString(r["MessageText"].ToString(), 65) + "...";
                }

                specific += "<span class='hoverText tooltip' title='" + this.Server.HtmlEncode(r["MessageText"].ToString().Replace("\r\n", "<br />")) + "'>" + this.Server.HtmlEncode(strTemp) + "</span><span class='dvMsgInitHidden'>" + this.Server.HtmlEncode(r["MessageText"].ToString().Replace("\r\n", "<br />")) + "</span><br /><br />";
            }

            lblMessage.Text = specific;

            upMessage.Update();
        }
        catch (Exception ce)
        {
        }
    }
}

public string TruncateLongString(string str, int maxLength)
{
    return str.Substring(0, maxLength);
}
```

As you can see from the following screenshot the `title` shows correctly but the message is all jumbled into one line:

[image]

Please help me resolve it.

Comment: Did you try to output your text directly before storing it to the database? Are linebreaks shown correctly?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The following CSS takes care of it:

```
white-space: pre-wrap;
```

Comment: This answer is a jewel! Much better then any other answer given here.

Comment: Solved my question for sure :)

Answer (score 1):

We've made a helper method that simply replaces \r\n, \n, and \r with the HTML break tag 
 for output. We store the text in the database with the raw \r \n characters, and during edit, TextArea honors the line break naturally.  Its only when showing on the "details page" in a span, that the conversion to a HTML break tag should be done.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to store formating in ddbb, you can use rtf or html tags for this. Rtf could be more suited for desktop apps, in your case, you'll need to store html tags among the text (p, br, etc)